# Is there a way in which I can add a "click" event listener on image and then I can further add class to it by using onclick in dropzone js?

Tags: javascript, html, css, laravel, dropzone.js

So, what I'm trying to do is that when I click on an uploaded image uploaded using dropzone js, then I want to add a "click" eventlistener on it. When I click on it then I want to add an "active" class on it that'll only be triggered when I click on it. Currently, I'm unable to achieve what I want to achieve. Basically, how can I add click eventlistener on the image when it is being uploaded through dropzone js.

JS REFERENCE

```
Dropzone.options.dropzone = {
paramName: "file",
autoProcessQueue: true,
parallelUploads: 1,
clickable: true,
maxFiles: 5,
maxFilesize: 1,
renameFile: function (file) {
    var dt = new Date();
    var time = dt.getTime();
    return time;
},
acceptedFiles: ".jpeg,.jpg,.png,.gif,.webp",
removedfile: function (file) {
    if (this.options.dictRemoveFile) {
        return Dropzone.confirm(
            "Are You Sure to " + this.options.dictRemoveFile,
            function () {
                if (file.previewElement.id != "") {
                    var name = file.previewElement.id;
                } else {
                    var name = file.upload.filename;
                }
                $.ajax({
                    headers: {
                        "X-CSRF-TOKEN": $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr(
                            "content"
                        ),
                    },
                    type: "DELETE",
                    url: "galleries/remove",
                    data: { filename: name },
                    success: function (data) {
                        alert(data.success);
                    },
                    error: function (e) {
                        console.log(e);
                    },
                });
                var fileRef;
                return (fileRef = file.previewElement) != null
                    ? fileRef.parentNode.removeChild(file.previewElement)
                    : void 0;
            }
        );
    }
},

createImageThumbnails: true,
timeout: 50000,
success: function (file, response) {
    console.log(response);
},
error: function (file, response) {
    return false;
},
init: function () {
    this.on("maxfilesexceeded", function (file) {
        this.removeFile(file);
    });
    this.on("addedfile", function (file) {
        file.previewElement.querySelector("[data-dz-name]").textContent =
            file.upload.filename;
       
    });
},

previewTemplate: `
<div class="dz-preview dz-file-preview dz-img-item">
<div class="dz-details"><div class="dz-filename"><span data-dz-name></span></div>
<div class="dz-size" data-dz-size></div></div>
<div class="dz-image"><img data-dz-thumbnail /></div>
<div class="dz-progress">
<span class="dz-upload" data-dz-uploadprogress></span>
</div>
<div class="dz-success-mark"><span>✔</span></div>
<div class="dz-error-mark"><span>✘</span></div>
<div class="dz-error-message"><span data-dz-errormessage></span></div>
<div class="dz-remove">
<a href="galleries/remove" id="delete-blog" class="icons-wrap delete" data-dz-remove>
<img src="/imgs/admin/icons/delete.svg" class="crud-icons delete">
</a>
</div>`,
 };
  const mediaSidebar = document.querySelector(".media-sidebar"),
  imgItem = document.querySelectorAll(".dz-preview.dz-img-item");

  imgItem.forEach((el) => {
  el.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    if (e.target === el) {
        console.log("hello g", e.target);
        mediaSidebar.classList.add("active");
     }
   });
  });
```

[image: output]

Comment: So, you want to preview uploaded image details on click of previewed image on right side, correct ?

Comment: Also, could you please confirm, that `imgItem = document.querySelectorAll(".dz-preview.dz-img-item");` this selector is working? coz in my dropzone with `.dz-img-item` class it's not working

Comment: Yes @MiteshRathod

Comment: No it's not working and also it isn't giving any error..

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll(".dz-preview.dz-img-item")` this one is not working, right?

Comment: Yes.. @MiteshRathod

Comment: You are getting an error coz, `.dz-img-item` class does not exist, so, try with only `.dz-preview` class